# Return Empty DataFrame when there's data exists in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dataset, jupyter

I'm new to python and I'm trying to retrieve specific data fields on my dataset.
There are ids and there are reviews according to ids. I want to fetch all the reviews only under one single id which I'm considering.
So I used this code.

```
df_new = df[df['recipe_id'] == '85009'] 
print(df_new)
```

It's returning

> Empty DataFrame Columns: [recipe_id, review] Index: []

But the dataset has data. below shown the data set.
[image]

When I try to fetch under a keyword in reviews, then it's working fine. The problem only happens to try to data under recipe_id
So what is the reason for this, and how do I fix this?
(Please let me know if the question is not clear.)

Comment: Perhaps your recipe_id values are numbers, not strings.

Comment: oh, That was the problem. How did I forget that?  Thank you so much. That was the problem. Fixed that. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

recipe_id is an integer. So I did remove the quotes of the recipe_id

```
df_new = df[df['recipe_id'] == 85009]
```

Then it works perfectly fine. Thanks to @topsail for the answer in the comments.